# How to find the cell name that contains an image object with openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to get programmatically the cell name that contains an image inside an excel sheet and I'm not sure how to get it working...

I've got the following code so far,

`

```
wb= openpyxl.load_workbook(link)

ws=wb.worksheets[0]

for image in ws._images:

     print(image)
```

`
the results are like this :

```
         <openpyxl.drawing.image.Image object at **0x00000164AD442408**> 
         <openpyxl.drawing.image.Image object at **0x00000164AD4AFB88**>
```

However i would like to know if i can get the cell position of each image: 
             Like this : Image 1 : **B22**
                         Image 2 : **F35**

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the position using the image's `_from` anchor:

```py
print(image.anchor._from.row, image.anchor._from.col)
```

Each image also has a `to` anchor, and both the `_from` and `to` anchors have offsets which tell you have far from the top-left corner the image is whithin a cell.